# Solving the one particle partition function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics

We have $N$ oscillators and each of them is described by the Hamiltonian:

$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{Kq^4}{4} $$

I have to compute the average total energy $\langle E\rangle$ of the $N$ oscillators. But to do so, first I have to compute the one particle partition function and to do so I have to solve the following integral:

$$Z_1 (V,T) = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}  e ^{-\beta \,H_1(p,q)}\,dp\,dq.$$

So in this case:

$$ Z_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}}\,dp \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-\beta \frac{Kq^4}{4}}\,dq. $$

I know this integral can be solved by the Gauss method, knowing that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}.$$

For the first integral I got:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}}\,dp = \sqrt{\frac{2m\pi}{\beta}}$$

**I am having difficulties solving the second one:**

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-\beta \frac{Kq^4}{4}}\,dq.$$

I have tried to make a the change of variables: $q^4 = a^2,$ but this does not simplify the calculation. **What method should I use?**

Once you get $Z_1$:

$$Z_N = (Z_1)^N.$$

Then you just have to apply:

$$\langle E \rangle = -\frac{ \partial \log(Z_N)}{\partial \beta}.$$

ANSWER

$$\langle E \rangle = \frac{3N}{4\beta}.$$

Comment: Wolfram Dev Platform gives an answer of $\Gamma(1/4)/(\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{\beta K}).$

Comment: Yes, I have solved the second integral using a software also but it appears the gamma function and I do not know how to interpret the solution in order to get < E >

Comment: For any $n > 0\, \int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}dx = \Gamma(1+\frac{1}{n})$ - perhaps there is an application here given the spiltting of the half-line may be achievable.

Comment: @AdrianKeister and Kevin, now I am thinking that the definite integrals should be from 0 to $\infty$ instead of from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ right?

Comment: @JD_PM: I doubt that. Check the definitions in your textbook or notes.

Comment: $\displaystyle Z_{1}$ definition lacks a division by $\displaystyle h$ ( $\displaystyle h$ is the $Planck\ Constant$ ) such that it becomes adimensional.

Comment: @FelixMarin: It wouldn't surprise me if that was textbook-dependent.

Comment: @AdrianKeister That's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, we have
\begin{align*}
Z_1&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}}\,dp \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-\beta \frac{Kq^4}{4}}\,dq \\
&=\sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi m}{\beta}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(1/4)}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{\beta K}} \\
&=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi m}{\beta}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(1/4)}{\sqrt[4]{\beta K}} \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi m}\,\Gamma(1/4)}{\beta^{3/4}\,K^{1/4}} \\
&=\beta^{-3/4}\,\frac{\sqrt{\pi m}\,\Gamma(1/4)}{K^{1/4}}.
\end{align*}
Next, following your procedure, we do
\begin{align*}
Z_N&=\left(Z_1\right)^{\,N} \\
&=\left(\beta^{-3/4}\,\frac{\sqrt{\pi m}\,\Gamma(1/4)}{K^{1/4}}\right)^{\!N}, \\
\langle E\rangle&=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta} \, \ln\left[\left(\beta^{-3/4}\,\frac{\sqrt{\pi m}\,\Gamma(1/4)}{K^{1/4}}\right)^{\!N}\,\right] \\
&=-N\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta} \, \ln\left[\beta^{-3/4}\,\frac{\sqrt{\pi m}\,\Gamma(1/4)}{K^{1/4}}\right] \\
&=-N\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta} \left[-\frac34\ln(\beta)+\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi m}\,\Gamma(1/4)}{K^{1/4}}\right) \right] \\
&=\frac{3N}{4\beta}.
\end{align*}
Here you can see that the $\Gamma(1/4)$ just goes away because of the logarithm.

Lesson for you: Trust the intermediate results (at least temporarily), and *keep going!*

Comment: You are right, the definition of < E > has a negative sign! My bad. Now fixed. Thanks for your advise :)